# Select labels of radio buttons in a fieldset

Tags: javascript, html, fieldset

I want to make it so when the user hovers over the label of radio buttons for a series of colours, the label's background changes to that colour using javascript in a .js file. I appear to be having difficulty selecting the element, however.  Nothing occurs when I hover over the labels, so I believe I have issues with selecting the labels. **I am not to use jQuery for this problem.**

```js
let colourLabel = document.getElementsByName("label");
colourLabel.addEventListener("mouseover",function(event)
{
    event.target.style.color = "white";
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = colourLabel.textContent;
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Colours</legend>
  <div>
   <input type="radio" name="colour" id="red" value="red" />
   <label for="red" name = "label">red</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you run the snippet I converted your code into, it will give you a clue as to the problem

Comment: Here is how to do what you wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/erasjg8o/

Comment: @mplungjan Can this be done through direct style modification by using the contents of the label?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but likely yes